# .Net Core 2.1 Web Api connection string using supplied User Id and Password for SQL Connection

Tags: c#, database-connection, asp.net-core-webapi, sql-server-express

I've been trying to get my application to use the supplied user id and password for connecting to my SQL Server but can't get anything to work.

Here is the setup, I have a laptop that I am developing on and a desktop that I am hosting the webapi on as well as the sql server.  When I run locally on the laptop connecting to the desktop sql server everything works (using User Id and Password).  However when I publish to the desktop and try to connect I get errors connecting to the sql server.

I've tried all settings for Trusted_Connection and Integrated Security as well as not supplying either.

Anything with Trusted_Connection set to false gives me these errors in the Windows Event Logs

- "Windows API call SHGetKnownFolderPath returned error code: 5. Windows system error message is: Access is denied."
- "Cannot get a local application data path. Most probably a user profile is not loaded. If LocalDB is executed under IIS, make sure that profile loading is enabled for the current user."

Anything with Trusted_Connection set to true tries to connect to the SQL Server using the IIS APPPOOL\… identity.

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=xxx\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=databaseName;User Id=userId;Password=password;Trusted_Connection=False;Integrated Security=False;"
```

Comment: It's nothing to do with the user and password. If the app is on the same machine as the server you should be able to use `.\SQLEXPRESS;...` to designate the local machine as the server.

Comment: Side note: if you can use Integrated Security (Trusted Connection) it would be more secure, just run the app pool under a user account with the least privilege necessary to perform the database operations you require.

Comment: So I added trusted connection, gave my IIS APPPOOL\TestAppPool a login for the database and read/write permissions on my database (same permissions that my passed used credentials had and could use the site locally). I tried changing connection to .\SQLEXPRESS. I can't get it to login successfully, now I get Login failed for user IIS APPPOOL\TestAppPool. So it is trying that user but it seems like the SQL server isn't allowing that user to login when though they have a server login security  and a database user security.

Comment: "... a login for database..." doesn't make sense because logins are for the server. **Users** are given access at the database level. And the AppPool identity cannot be given a password so you need a regular Windows account under which to run the app pool.